# C++ improving palette indexing algorithm

Tags: c++, indexing, bitmap

I have a game engine that indexes colors of some bitmaps which allows using some of the crazy effects of olde (color strobing etc.). Sadly, the indexing algorithm is neither slow nor fast, but since the spritesheets these days are gigantic it really adds up. Currently, loading a single large spritesheet can take 150+ milliseconds, which is an eternity, relatively speaking.

This is the algorithm:

```
auto& palette = p->pal;     // vector
auto& lookup  = p->lookup;  // vector_map

palette.reserve(200); // There are on average ~100 unique colors
palette.push_back(0); // Index zero is the blank color

uint32_t lastColor = 0;
uint32_t lastPalette = 0;

for (size_t i = 0; i < pixels; i++)
{
    const auto color = data[i];
    if (color == lastColor)
    {
        data[i] = lastPalette;
        continue;
    }
    else if (color == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    uint32_t j = 0;
    const auto& it = lookup.find(color);
    if (it != lookup.end()) {
        j = it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        j = palette.size();
        palette.push_back(color);
        lookup.emplace(color, j);
    }

    lastColor = color;
    // Write the index back to the bitmap:
    // (this is just a GPU texture encoding, don't mind it)
    data[i] = (j & 255) | ((j >> 8) << (8 + 6));
    lastPalette = data[i];
}
```

The base algorithm is fairly straight-forward:
Go through each pixel, find or create an entry for it (the color), write the index back to the image.

Now, can you parallelize this? Probably not. I have tried with OMP and regular threads. It's simply not going to be fast because regardless of how much time you save by going through each portion of the image separately, at the end you have to have a common set of indexes that apply throughout the whole image, and those indexes have to be written back to the image. Sadly, finding the unique colors first and then writing back using parallelization is also slower than doing it once, sequentially. Makes sense, doesn't it?

Using a bitset has no function here. Knowing whether a color exists is useful, but the colors are 32-bit, which makes for 2^32 bits (aka. 530MB). In contrast, 24-bits is only ~2MB, which might be a micro-optimization. I'm not really looking for that anyway. I need to cut the time by 10x.

So, any ideas? Would it be possible to process 4 or 8 colors at the same time using SSE/AVX?

Comment: I don't really understand the context. Can't this be precomputed? Also, what type are you using for the `lookup`?

Comment: I don't see how threads would not help if your images are so large that this takes 150ms. Just to be clear, are you saying that you have tried the following? 1) Build N palette indexes for N sub-portions of the image using N threads. 2) Merge the N indexes in the main thread. 3) Apply the merged index using N threads to the N sub-portions of the image. (Of course, spin your threads up only once, don't create new threads for steps 1) and 3) for each image.) This seems like it should be a clear win.

Comment: Also, have you tried keeping the palette vector sorted? If you have 100-200 colors on average, that seems a bit over the number where binary search may start to become faster than a linear search.

Comment: @Mat I have briefly considered creating a processing tool that we can send the images through so that they are already indexed when loading, but it would just be so much easier if we didn't have to. It's for sure going to be the fastest solution. The type for `lookup` is an EASTL vector_map, which is just a regular map with nodes in sequential memory.

Comment: Have you considered the energy/battery cost of having that done on every device your game runs on for every time it is run? :) You already have the code to do it, making a tool out of it and integrating that to your build sounds trivial. And you can then parallelize trivially by processing multiple images at once.

Comment: @Mat That's very true. I'll accept that as a solution, I think. You know artists really don't like tools that aren't point and click, that's the real reason haha.